# deploy stack to remote swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Good morning,
I'm approaching docker swarm now and I'm having trouble finding some information.
My goal is to create a gitlab or travis deployment to my swarm cluster, I created my manager node with the docker swarm init command and created a docker registry as a service; as indicated in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/).

Here is my very simple dockerfile

```
FROM node:9.5.0

ADD . .

RUN yarn install

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

and here my compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  healthcheck:
    image: <registry_url>:<registry_port>/healthcheck
    build: .
```

Launching the command

```
docker-compose push
```

from another not-swarm server in the work fine and my image is correctly uploaded to the registry.

So now I think I have to deploy my stack with something like this (remember that I am running the following command from another server)

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<my_manager_url>:<my_manager_port>
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml healthcheck
```

but the swarm server reject me and i don't know witch is the right port.

I think it must be configured in some way but I have not found anything about it.

I'm on the right way? Could you suggest me the documentation I did not find?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to reach the remote `Docker Daemon` to push your `compose.yml`. But the problem is by default `Docker Daemon` is only bound to unix socket.

To do so, on your remote server, you will have to alter  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file and change `ExecStart` to...

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

then,

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and restart

```
service docker restart
```

I wouldn't recommend you this setup without securing the Daemon with `TLS`. If you don't use `TLS` anyone can reach out to your server and deploy containers.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yea, like @Ahab says at end, you don't want to enable TCP on the docker service unless it's secured with TLS. Two options:

Follow the [documentation for enabling TLS on the remote daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/).

Use Docker Cloud's easy ["bring your own swarm" feature to manage TLS for you](https://youtu.be/VJmbCioYKGg).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `export DOCKER_HOST="ssh://user@server:22"`

Comment: I don't think this was an option when the original question was asked / answered -- but this probably the best answer for most folks today. See https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/ and the docs at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/ if you search for both "DOCKER_HOST" and "ssh" there.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will deploy a compose file as a stack to a remote host. The remote host must be a known host before running the command.

```
docker -H ssh://<remote-host-credentials> stack deploy -c <path-to-compose-file> <stack-name>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).